# Layouting problems with JavaFX Region

Tags: layout, javafx, border, subclass, region

I want to write a new class that extends Region containing a StackPane inside. But I'm getting into trouble when I add insets to it like padding or a border. Here is a simplified example of the class:

```
public class CustomPane extends Region
{
    private ToggleButton testControl = new ToggleButton("just a test control");
    private StackPane rootPane = new StackPane(testControl);

    public CustomPane()
    {
        getChildren().add(rootPane);
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: #257165; -fx-border-width: 10;");
    }
}
```

And that is how the result looks like:

[image]

If I try to move the StackPane by calling

```
rootPane.setLayoutX(10);
rootPane.setLayoutY(10);
```

then the Region just grows:

[image]

But really I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

(The third image was created by extending StackPane instead of Region, which already manages the layouting stuff correctly. Unfortunately I have to extend Region since I want to keep `getChildren()` protected.)

Okay, I tried to handle the layout calculation but I didn't come up with it. Could experts give me some advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StackPane` uses the [`insets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#insetsProperty) for layouting the (managed) children. `Region` doesn't do this by default. Therefore you need to override the [`layoutChildren`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layoutChildren--) with something that uses these `insets`, e.g.:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    Insets insets = getInsets();
    double top = insets.getTop(),
            left = insets.getLeft(),
            width = getWidth() - left - insets.getRight(),
            height = getHeight() - top - insets.getBottom();

    // layout all managed children (there's only rootPane in this case)
    layoutInArea(rootPane,
            left, top, // offset of layout area
            width, height, // available size for content
            0,
            HPos.LEFT,
            VPos.TOP);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. So `layoutInArea` is the method I was looking for. Instead of `getInsets` I would use `snappedLeftInset` and the other three.